# Slow application performance in one location

Tags: performance, application

We have a problem that perplexing both of us in our department. We have a video viewing application that we need to have loaded on a workstation to be used in a particular location. When we load a camera layout in our lab, it takes something in the neighborhood of 10-12 seconds to load 16 cameras. When we take it to the other location across campus, it takes 2 mins 15 sec to load. We have tried 2 different computers with the same results. We thought it might be related to the network, so we finally loaded the video viewer on a laptop, and it behaves just fine. We have tried several things and are standing around scratching our heads. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's some pertinent (maybe) information:

- All three computers are running Windows 7.
- The two desktops are Dell OptiPlex 960's, the laptop a Dell Latitude 6330.
- All three computers run with comparable times in our lab (approx. 10-12 sec).
- The two desktops BOTH take almost exactly 2 min 15 sec when in place across campus.
- The laptop when connected to the same network drop across campus loads in 10-12 secs.
- We disabled all Windows firewalls with no success. (although it did speed it up in our lab).
- We checked configuration on the port on the switch and it is configured exactly the same as the one in our lab.
- We installed updated NIC drivers on the desktops. Still slow.
- We forced the switch port to a specific speeds. All still slow.
- Changed out network cable. Still slow.
- Changed ports on the switch. Still slow.
- Checked the switch for errors, we don't see any.
- Tried a different switch in the same building (either end) same results (fine in lab, slow in field).

We thought at first it would have to be network related because 2 computers both exhibited the same behavior (good in one place not in another), however the laptop works just fine. We thought about it being something with the desktops, however, they work just fine in one our lab.

Anyone think of anything we're missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a check at MTU from the slow location, just test using ping (you can find many guides on how perform this test over the Internet). Packet fragmentation may sometimes have a role in slowing down network communications.

Comment: I'll have our network guy try it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's a system that we can only take down on Tuesdays, when it's not being used. I tried the MTU test, and the maximum packet size I could enter on the command line was 1472 so I don't think the packets are being fragmented. I also tried an OptiPlex 980 and it worked fine in the lab, but didn't work correctly in the field.